# Is it possible to write unit tests for rust build scripts?

Tags: rust

I developed a fairly long [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html). Now I need to add a set of unit tests to build.rs file. I tried to do the same as I do for regular files:

```rust
// build.rs

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn test1() {
        //...
    }
}
```

but seems it didn't work. Running tests doesn't result in running `test1`.

Comment: Not sure if testing build scripts is currently possible, but here's an annoying workaround: you can make the build script logic its own lib crate, and import it as a build dependency in the main crate. Then test as usual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [issue #1581](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1581), that was closed as "needs an RFC". So this is not possible currently. The workaround, as @MeetTitan said, is to extract the build script logic into its own crate and make it a [build-dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#build-dependencies) and call it from the build script.

Comment: I already have one lib crate in my main project. Does that mean I must move script logic to my lib crate and make my build script depend on the lib crate?

Comment: @s4eed It's probably preferable to move it to its own crate, to reduce compilation time.

Comment: In that case, should I use workspaces?

Comment: @s4eed You don't have to, but it will likely help you.